# java enum to arraylist card deck

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

Problem: only the memory address is out.print of arraylist. For example: Card@14318bb.

I really hope that this is a new question. I've looked and looked and read and learnt, but still seem to have this one in a twist! Code:

***DeckMain.java***

```
public class DeckMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Card> newDeck = new ArrayList<Card>( );

        Card.Rank[] ranks = Card.Rank.values();  
        Card.Suit[] suits = Card.Suit.values(); 

        for (Card.Suit suit : suits) {
            for (Card.Rank rank : ranks) {
                newDeck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
            }
        }

        int n = newDeck.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1)  + ": " + newDeck.get(i));       
        }
    }
}
```

***Card.java***

```
public class Card {
    public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES; }

    public enum Rank { TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, 
                       NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE; }

    final Rank rank;
    final Suit suit;

    public Card (final Rank rank, final Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using an ArrayDeque. It combines stack and queue data structures and provides methods that are more convenient for a deck of cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't override the `toString()` method in your Card class. Hence you use the one herited from the `Object` class :

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Override it in your `Card` class :

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return suit.name()+"-"+rank.name();
}
```

Comment: This was great. I get it. The help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to your Card class add following method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return this.rank + " " + this.suit;
}
```

Comment: `this.rank` and `this.suit` gives same apparent output as `rank.name()` and `suit.name()`. At this moment I am still working with what `this.` and `that.` really mean. Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @kaicarno inside class method `this.rank` and just `rank` are synonyms, needed only if you have function argument, I wrote it just because it my habit to distinguish class properties and just variables